# Android app doesn't start after adding admob

Tags: android, admob

I am working on an android app in which I am using admob to display ads but after I have put banner ad from admob it fails to start.
Here is my xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
android:background="@color/bg"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:ignore="NamespaceTypo">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/lml"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/lmr"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/lmt"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/lmb"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lpp1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/content"
        android:textColor="@color/content"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:background="@color/bg"
        android:text="@string/lpp1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added this in the manifest file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

I have read many questions related to this on stackoverflow and searched for this problem and tried a few things but still couln't solve the problem. Can anyone point out where it the problem.

Java file details

```
  MobileAds.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxx");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.gurjeet.application, PID: 15393
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gurjeet.application/com.example.gurjeet.application.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.gurjeet.application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3209)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you please post crash logs?

Comment: Share your java file also

Comment: added the logcat

Comment: `mAdView` is null. You missing something in manifest file or in gradle.

Comment: I have added the dependency in the gradle file and the required details in manifest file as shown in the question.

Comment: Got the solution. Actually I was displaying ads in another activity, not main activity and I was adding the java code in the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that please checkout whether you had add the AdView to the layout of your activity.
Something like this:

```
layout = findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
layout.addView(mAdView);
```

then you could load ads with the AdView:

```
mAdView.loadAds(adRequest);
```